# Modify Scilab/Xcos Block in Scilab 6 Gateway Function

Tags: api, scilab, xcos

I would like to *modify* an Xcos block from within a gateway function using the new (non-legacy) Scilab API, for example, replace the block's *model* property by a new model structure. In other words, do the same as the Scilab command(s):

```
m = scicos_model()
block.model = m
```

However, I did not manage to achieve this behavior with the functions from Scilab 6 API: a block created by `standard_define()` is correctly passed to my gateway function, where this argument is available as `scilabVar` of type `128`. On the other hand, the Scilab help claims that a block is a "*scilab **tlist** of type "Block" with fields : graphics, model, gui and doc*".

#### Attempts

Assume `scilabVar block` taken from gateway function argument, string constants of type `wchar_t[]`, `scilabVar model` holding the result of `scicos_model()`:

1. Application of function `scilab_setTListField (env, block, "model", model)` returns error status (as its equivalents for `MList` and `List` do)
2. Knowing that property `.model` is at index 3, a `setfield (3, model, block)`  called through `scilab_call ("setfield", ...)` also fails.

   - This is not surprising: when called directly from  the Scilab command line, it ends up with
     `setfield:  Wrong type for input argument #3: List expected.` .
   - However, a `getfield (3, block)` works, so that at least read access to the block's data fields is possible.
3. An external helper function

   ```
   function block = blockSetModel (block, model)
     block.model = model
   endfunction
   ```

   also called through `scilab_call("blockSetModel", ...)` actually returns a block with changed model,
   but the original block passed to this function remains unchanged.
   Although ugly, this gives at least a way to construct an individual block structure
   which needs to be returned as a **copy**.

#### Summary

- So, is there simply a function missing in the API,  which returns the `TList` (or whatever) behind a type `128` pointer variable?
- Or is there any other approach to this problem I was unable to discover?

#### Background

The goal behind is to move the block definition task from the usual interfacing "gui" function (e.g. a Scilab script `MyBlock.sci`) into own C code. For this purpose, the interfacing function is reduced to a wrapper around a C gateway, which, for example, uses`scilab_call ("standard_define",...)` to create a new block when being called with parameter `job=="define"`.
Modification of the contained `model` and `graphics` objects through the Scilab API works fine since these are standard list types. However, getting or setting these objects as attributes `.model` and `.graphics` of the
original block fails as described above.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Scilab/Xcos 6.0.0, the data-structure behind a block is no more an MList (or TList) so you cannot upgrade the model to your own MList. All the data behind are stored using a classical MVC within a C++ coded Block.hxx.

On each try you made, a serialization/deserialization happens to reconstruct the block model field as a Scilab value.

Could you describe what kind of field you want to append/edit regarding the block structure ? Some of the predefined fields might be enough to pass extra information.

Comment: For info about the background, please see the **edit** above. Basically, I can live with the described workaround. But shouldn't there be a possibility in the Scilab API to also manipulate special objects like an Xcos block?